# Laravel 5.8 Logout, Back, Clicked Button And Error

Tags: laravel

I use the default authentication from Laravel, and after logging it directs to my cms template. Then I cut the logout section from the Laravel original page and pasted it to my cms template for the logout section only. However, once I logout and clicked back on the browser the previous page can be accessed, but after I click a button for example "Edit" the notification below showed up.

> Trying to get property" name 'of non-object (View: C: \ xampp \ htdocs
> \ mylaravel \ resources \ views \ master \ header.blade.php)

What I want is that when clicking on the "Edit" button or other buttons it returning to the login page and there is no error like above. How can I do that? (I've tried `session::flush` and other things didn't really work. Now I just need when the user clicked any processing buttons it will direct to the login page after logout).

**My Template View:**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
   <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
      <h8>You Are Loged as,</h8>
      <b>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</b><span class="caret"></span>
   </a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"> {{ __('Logout') }}</a>
   <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
   </form>
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: you can add middleware('auth'); to your route like, Route::post('editPost', function () {
    // or you can add your controller
})->middleware('auth');

Comment: You have an error inside tag <h8> at header.blade.php file, you can check if user is auth ```<h8>You Are Loged as,</h8> <b>{{Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->name : "user was logout" }}</b><span class="caret"></span></a>``` . Is HTML have a tag <h8> ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default auth middleware in multiple routes by creating a route group.

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::post('/editPost', 'YourPostController@edit');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just simple, not on the route and in laravel 5.8 doesn't really need routing (you need use routing if you made a custom auth and redirect pages). Add this library in your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

And adding this also in your controller:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->user =  \Auth::user();
    }
```

I haven't found the solution for back button on the browser and redirect to other or login page, at least this what I can do. It prevent button on your page operate and redirect to login page.